# Javascript Autofill entries of any websites

Tags: javascript, html, fill

I have simple HTML/Javascript knowledge and I am trying to create an auto-fill script so when a user clicks a link on my webpage, it opens that link AND automatically input/fill the username and password textboxes of that website.

If I do INSPECT ELEMENT I can see the ID of those textboxes of that website but I don't know the code to go to a website and fill the fields. I am not familliar with JQuery, I only know Javascript, VB, and HTML. I am new to Java but I'm learning.

Comment: you mean fill the inputs on another website than the one your script is on?

Comment: Are you looking for a userscript? or does the "other website" exist in an iframe? You're not really being clear what the problem is here.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you want to add this functionality? Maybe a different approach is more suited than an explanation on how to implement this correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys. We often login to multiple websites of our clients and it's tedious to keep loging in to each of these sites especialy since each of them automatically logs me off after 20 minutes. I want to create a js to open one of those sites and login automatically depending on which site and what login credentials to use

Answer (score 1):

This is probably impossible due to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)  countermeasures, which prevents you from injecting code into a website from a differen origin.

Answer (score -2):

try the html5 placeholder attribute http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder. I beleive thats what you are looking for.